# How to conceal file in deployment package?

Tags: c#, deployment, vb6, windows-installer

In an upgrade to a VB6/C# product I need to include a file.  This file will be copied by the app to a server location when a certain button is clicked.  Once there it will stay there and be utilised by the application from then on.

This file needs to be included in the deployment package so that it can be copied to the server location.  If I just include the file in the app directory, then every workstation that installs the product will have this file.  The file is of a slightly sensitive nature, which means that I would prefer that it is not just sitting in its raw form on each workstation.

Is there a way I can have the file available for copying, but not have it accessible to someone who is able to look into the app's folder on each workstation?

I do not want to deploy the file directly to the server location because I don't want to have the customer's staff involved in placing specific files on the server.

Answer (score 1):

Encrypt the content of the file. Decrypt it while copying to server. Or perhaps you keep it's encryption after it's moved to the server.

You could perhaps include the file as an embedded resource in one of the binaries of the application. It would be somewhat less accessible to non developers at least.

Last option is to update the server itself and give it the files so the clients aren't responsible for bringing it there. Of course I don't know what creates the requirements you have.

Comment: I'd prefer not to involve the server staff. Too many questions and delays!

Comment: @CraigJ perhaps your installer runs with the same permissions as the application. The installer could do the copying instead of the app if that were the case.

Comment: It would then be copying the file everytime it installs which is undesirable.

Comment: @CraigJ If the file exists don't do anything is a very typical installer action?

Comment: At this point the 'server location' is a variable. I don't think the installer could know where it is unless I had much more colloboration with the customer.

Comment: Why wouldn't a user see this file when they browse the file share?  Doesn't sound very "concealed" anyway.

Comment: Because this file share is not mapped to a drive for the users.  They simply don't know it exists.

Comment: @CraigJ If the server staff is remotely competent they should prevent third party apps from dropping files on their servers' harddisks. I'd say: do  involve them!

Comment: @Dabblernl: my app does have write access to the server folder. My approach is to try to do it via the app, but if that fails I will have to involve them.

Comment: @CraigJ If the app knows its folders, so can the installer. You write both don't you?

Comment: @Dabblernl: The customer's staff modify the installer for their needs including the server location.

Comment: @CraigJ Then again the customers know the server location.

Comment: I'd go with resources approach. The file sits in one of the application binaries. Yes, it exists on the file system but it's not directly accessible. Otherwise your installer must be always accessible to the application when it wants to get this file, which is hard to guarantee. Additionally there's no easy way to extract a single file from msi database unless it's stored in binary table rather than embedded cab with other files.